# React-native fbsdk get name and email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm working in with react-native-fbsdk. I want to get username and email to show up to the user when they're registered to the app in order to create a profile for the app, but no data is shown. How can I get these data and how can I show it in a different screen.

This is my code

```js
import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk'
import { LoginButton,AccessToken,GraphRequest,GraphRequestManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk';


const {
  LoginManager,
} = FBSDK;
```

```js
<LoginButton
        readPermissions={['public_profile']}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                      '/me?fields=name,picture',
                      null,
                      this._responseInfoCallback
                    );
                    // Start the graph request.
                    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
  _responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
    } else {
      alert('Result Name: ' + result.name);
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I retrieve facebook login while I using firebase.**

1. **import this file:**

   import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
   import { AccessToken, LoginManager } from "react-native-fbsdk";
2. **Firebase login code work when I click button:**

   export const fbLogin = () => {

   ```
   LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"])
     .then(result => {
       if (result.isCancelled) {
         console.log("Login was cancelled");
       }
       return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
     })
     .then(data => {
       const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
         data.accessToken
       );
      firebase
       .auth()
       .signInWithCredential(credential)
       .then(result => {
        Toast.show({
         text: "Sucessfully",
         position: "top"
       });
      console.log("Successfully Login", result);
    })
     .catch(error => {
      console.log("Failed", error);
        });
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log("fail", err);
     });
   ```

   };

I retrive my facebook login data

```
 console.log("Successfully Login", result);
```

**result** contains username, email, picture and ..ect credentials

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use firebase,

```
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me?fields=name,email,picture.type(large)',
        null,
        this._responseInfoCallback
      );
      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();


_responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
    } else {
      this.setState({ userName: result.name, userEmail: result.email ,userPic:result.picture.data.url});
              AsyncStorage.setItem("UserName",this.state.userName);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem("Email", this.state.userEmail);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem("UserPic", this.state.userPic);

      //  SharedPreferences.setItem("UserName", this.state.userName);
      //       SharedPreferences.setItem("Email", this.state.userEmail);
      //       SharedPreferences.setItem("UserPic", this.state.userPic);
      console.log("Picture"+ this.state.userPic + "Name" + this.state.userName + "Email" + this.state.userEmail);
    }
  }
```